# "I hate SharePoint"

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I work in the IT department for my company and I have been promoted to SharePoint admin for a while. I have spent a lot of time cleaning it up and getting ready for new projects in SharePoint. I am very passionate about SharePoint, but my fellow IT members are not. I hear on the daily "I hate SharePoint".

I would like to change this attitude. I believe part of the problem is they don't really know what SharePoint is for. They believe it is just a file folder that takes a lot of clicks to get there. I feel if I can get my fellow IT team changed to "SharePoint is awesome" I can change the attitude of the company, and I can get the ball rolling here.

Has anyone had any experience with this? How did you handle this? Do you know of any good short videos explaining what SharePoint is, what it can do, and its possibilities? After I successfully get my team on the same page, I want to hold a seminar on SharePoint with the business. There are a few people on my side, but the person that handled it before me cared 0 about her job and it ruined SharePoint for the company.

Help me fix it, please!

Comment: I would suggest rewording this as a series of specific challenges and the best way to overcome them, for example "What are good methods to encourage user uptake of Sharepoint?" and "What features does Sharepoint offer to distinguish it from similar products?".

Comment: This is an <everyday> situation in <everywhere>. You are not supposed to make people smile, if they don't feel like that. You can train colleagues for more efficient use of SharePoint, but in all fairness SharePoint sometimes still takes a couple of too many clicks to get a thing done, while on another day it does just what expected they way you hoped. (Then there are those days it doesn't allow you to do it, which creates *opinions*.) Also SharePoint isn't a secret tool with unicorn functionality - there are many others, and some have used SP before, some have fallen in love with another.

Comment: @ThomasGass approaches a more better format. In any matter, you should form the question without falling to the traps mentioned in the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).